# wordpress rest api issue in inserting post meta value while inserting post

Tags: wordpress, rest

Here is my code. I have an issue while inserting a new post using `WordPress REST API`. With given code, Post inserted successfully but the post meta field remains empty.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery( document ).ready( function ( $ ) {
            //Create Cause
            $( '#frm_create_campaign' ).on( 'submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var title = $('#cmp_title').val();
                var content = $('#post_submission_content').val();
                var meta    =   {'gdlr-current-funding':"0"};
                var status = 'draft';

                    var data = {
                        title: title,
                        content: content,                       
                        meta: meta
                    };              

                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: POST_SUBMITTER.root + 'wp/v2/cause',
                    data: data,
                    beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', POST_SUBMITTER.nonce );
                    },
                    success : function( response ) {
                        console.log( response );
                        alert( POST_SUBMITTER.success );
                    },
                    fail : function( response ) {
                        console.log( response );
                        alert( POST_SUBMITTER.failure );
                    }

                });

            });//End Create Cause
    </script>
```

Comment: I think you need to customize "wp/v2/cause" API for custom post meta data.

Comment: Any suggestion please? Right now custom post creating perfectly fine. Just having issue with post meta fields.

Comment: Is it woocommerce site?

Comment: No, its not a woocommerce site.

Comment: Okay good, please tell which plugin you are using.

Comment: I am using Chairty Hub wordpress theme. The link is https://themeforest.net/item/charity-hub-charity-nonprofit-fundraising-wp/7481543
The plugin name is gdlr-cause.
I am trying to create Cause from front-end.